# Write search methods in array by Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have an array it has `(id,name,salary)`
I want to search specific `ID` using Employee search method, my code is:

```
Employee SearchID(int i_d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
        boolean check = true;
        if (staff[i].id == i_d) {
            System.out.println("Id: " + staff[i].id + ", name: " + staff[i].name + " and salary: " + staff[i].salary);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, no record exists with record id = " + i_d);
        }
    }
 return staff[i].id;
}
```

Comment: so, what's the issue?

Comment: I don't see what is the question.

Comment: I have error and can't complete

Comment: Do you have compiler error or runtime error? What error message?

Comment: If you have an error then the very least you could do is tell us what the error is.

Comment: I have compiler error in return

Answer (score 0):

Your SearchID method returns an Employee object but you return a primitive type. (staff[i].id) You must change return type of your method.

Comment: How I can change type?

Comment: That would depend upon if you really do want to return an employee and you need to change the return type or do you really want to return the ID and you need to change the method signature?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your method like this:

```
Employee SearchID(int i_d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < staff.length; i++) {
        if (staff[i].id == i_d) {
            System.out.println("Id: " + staff[i].id + ", name: " + staff[i].name + " and salary: " + staff[i].salary);
            return staff[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorry, no record exists with record id = " + i_d);
    return null;
}
```

And, of course, you need to handle the `null` result after calling `SearchID` properly.

Comment: You can remove the `check` variable given it's never used.